# Django string in unicode pattern

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Django when i send the following string from an ajax submit i get the following string in unicode.How to decode this

```
    $.post("/records/save_t/",snddata,
     function(data){
     if(data == 0 ){
     }
      },"json");
```

In django

```
def save_t(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        qd = request.GET
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        qd = request.POST
    map_str = qd.getlist('map_str')
    logging.debug(map_str)
```

Output is `[u'##1##@1//##2##@1//']`. How can I convert this to a string? `str(map_str)` did not work.

Also how to get the values in the pattern

```
 str = map_str.split("//")
 for s in map_str.split("//"):
     ...
     ...
```

Comment: You don't need to convert `unicode` to a string. A `unicode` object **IS** a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think you need to convert it to a string? What's wrong with it as Unicode? It should be perfectly usable as it is.

In any case, what you have is a *list* containing a single unicode string (because you've used `getlist`, which always unsurprisingly returns a list). Is the actual problem just that you want to get the actual data out of the list? Then use `map_str[0]` (of course, map_str is a bad name, because it's not a string but a list).

Or, don't use `getlist`, but a simple `get` to get a string rather than a list.